# COM Applications not working

Tags: asp-classic, com+

Our Test web server recently went down and we lost COM+ Applications installations.  I am trying to reinstall the COM Applications.  I have the installed the COM Applications and have the Identity set to run as Local Service.  I have Security set to Perform access checks at the process and component level.  The activation type is Server Application.

Environment:
Windows Server 2003
Classic ASP

I have verified that ASP is installed and works.  I get a 500 Internal Server error when the page gets to a point to call CreateObject.

There must be a security setting somewhere that I am missing.  I have tried giving Local Service Account and Network Service account full permissions on the root folder housing the .dll's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  We had to go into IIS, view the website properties, go to the Home Directory, Click on Configuration and then the Options tab and finally check the "Enable Parent Path" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Can't pinpoint it because the possible causes are legion.

There should be a setting in ASP that will report the HRESULT of the failed CreateObject call, instead of a useless 500 - Internal Error. From there, it should be easier to go on.

Aren't you unsure about LocalService, too? Shouldn't it be NetworkService instead?

Sorry that this is rather meager.

Comment: Where do I find this setting for ASP?

Comment: The IIS management console should have such a setting, maybe on the ASP tab.

Comment: In the IIS Manager, IIs Section, click on ASP. Under "Debuggin Properties" change the debugging, logging, and "send errors to browser" options to true.

Comment: I don't see this menu option.  I am running Windows Server 2003.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3c7830b4-df5c-41a2-9890-c201eb774c89.mspx?mfr=true There you go. That's where it is in 2003. After you turn those two options on, recreate your error and post the results in an edit to your question.